# Validação de modelo com scope em Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validação, active-record

Suponha os modelos:

```ruby
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :cs
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
end
```

Se eu quiser que um atributo de C seja único no escopo de B eu posso fazer isto:

```ruby
class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
  validates :atributo, presence: true,
                       uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false,
                                     scope: :b_id,
                                     message: 'precisa ser único' }
end
```

Mas como faço se quiser que ele seja único no escopo de A, sendo que não tenho `a_id` no tabela C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer dessa forma, realmente seria necessário criar a coluna `a_id` na tabela `C`.

Assim, além de você pode usar a validação pré-definida de `:uniqueness`, você poderá criar uma restrição de chave única no banco, o que é fundamental para garantir a unicidade em caso de acessos concorrentes. Para isso, adicione no migration:

```
    add_index :cs, [:a_id, :atributo], unique: true
```

Para setar o valor de `a_id` em `C`, sugiro criar um callback `before_validation`:

```
    before_validation :set_a_id
    def set_a_id
      self.a_id = b.a_id
    end
```

A solução alternativa seria usar uma [validação customizada](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations).

Comment: Terei que criar mais colunas de referências mesmo, senão ficaria muito complexo. No meu caso, na verdade, eu tenho até mais de 3 modelos cascateados. Valeu a força. =)